# CoreMotion framework

Tags: compass-geolocation

I recently was doing a compass, to involve CoreMotion framework, but I checked for a long time did not find information on how to implement this framework the effect of the compass, hoping to get everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

- Apple's [Core Motion Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html)
- Apple's [Event Handling Guide for iOS: Core Motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW26)
- Apple's CoreMotionTeaPot from [WWDC ’10 Sample Code](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645)
- [Get Moving with Core Motion](http://HTTP://WWW.SLIDESHARE.NET/JBLOCKSOM/CORE-MOTION-PRESENTATION) — Jonathan Blocksom
- [Getting you started with CoreMotion](http://files.ludwigschubert.de/cm.pdf) — Ludwig Schubert
- A similar question: [make a compass application in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013840/make-a-compass-application-in-ipad/6014474#6014474)

Answer (score 0):

My "Helloworld" CoreMotion:

1) Add CoreMotion.framework

2) in .h file:

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

3) in .m file:

```
CMMotionManager *myMotionManager= [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
myMotionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1/60;
[myMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical  toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
     double x = myMotionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.x;
     double y = myMotionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.y;
     double z = myMotionManager.deviceMotion.magneticField.field.z;
    NSLog(@"Strength of Earth's magnetic field= %8.2f",sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z));
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%8.2f", sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)];
}];
```