# make a compass application in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I would like to make a compass application that will specify the geographic directions(north, east, west, south),

So i used CoreLocation framework in my application. I found in many forums that when this function `[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];` calls it will automatically call the function: `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading`

But in my application the second function is not automatically invoked, so i cant able to make my application, Please help me.......
My code is given bellow:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
    NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
    NSString *headingstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",newHeading.trueHeading];
    trueHeading.text = headingstring;
    [headingstring release];

    NSString *magneticstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",newHeading.magneticHeading];
    magneticHeading.text = magneticstring;
    [magneticstring release];
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    //Start the compass updates.
    if (CLLocationManager.headingAvailable ) {     
        [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No Heading Available: ");
        UIAlertView *noCompassAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Compass!" message:@"This device does not have the ability to measure magnetic fields." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [noCompassAlert show];
        [noCompassAlert release];
    }
}
```

### please help me

Sreekumar Kalarikkal
India

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. Hmm.

Comment: But, when I debugging, its seen that the method is not get invoked.   :(

Comment: In what class is that code? How do you add the view? Does the view appear on screen?

Comment: @rckoenes Lot's of iPads with compass available...

Comment: @Eiko, well only the 3G ones, the wifi ones do not have a Compass.

Comment: @rckoenes This is not true. *Every* iPad has a digital compass.

Comment: @Eiko, you are wright, My butt my Ipad compass does not work, it give out an incorrect reading, looks like the Wi-Fi version has lots of problems with the compass. My iPhone gives the correct heading directly.

Comment: only iPhone 3gs and iPod having the compass hardware i think...

Comment: @Eiko. The code in compassViewControler.m file. Its a view based application.The view is displaying perfecly with two labels having default values, my code will change the text of labels, but that methode is not invoking. I am using an iPad simulator.

Comment: Are you sure your viewDidLoad method is not called? Place a NSLog at the start of the method to make sure... Also, what compass information do you expect from the simulator?!

Comment: viewDidLoad method is invoked perfectly, but the problem is with the     [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];    method. This line in the above code is executing, but according to the property of this methode, it will automatically invoke "    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading    " method, but its not happening, it should be executed for my application to run properly. Actually I am trying to make a compass application...... Help me please.......

Comment: I got it, When I run it on the device, it works perfectly.... thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is just no heading available on the iOS simulator (and your code is giving the appropriate alert view).

On the device, this code just works fine.

(Tested your code both on simulator and device)

Comment: @Eiko:   Ya thank you, When i run it on device it works perfectly. Now i got the direction value. How can i make a graphical compass with an arrow using this value?

Comment: (!!) arghskhfskjf good catch! :) @Sreekumar add a UIImageView subview with the arrow image and do myarrowView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(trueHeading);

Comment: @Jano: Thank you very much Jano. Can you please post some code for this. It will be very helpful, because i am new to iPhone developement. Thank You.

Comment: In your viewController there should be a `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;` (plus the `@synthesize view` in the implementation) that you need to connect in Interface Builder to the UIView in your window. Then add a `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *arrow;` and `self.arrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]; [self.view addSubView:arrow];`. To animate add the transform above in the didUpdateHeading method. It's very easy to do, creating a compass is more about the design of the graphics than anything else. Try it and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Jano. I am going to try and will inform you if any confusion occures.

Comment: @Jano: I tried it with an arrow image, but the image(arrow.png) is displaying in the simulator, but not in the device.... What will be the problem????

Comment: Hard to say, maybe you should post a separate question with details.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal ball says you are missing the protocol in your interface header: `@interface xxxx : xxx <CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

Comment: Thank You jano, But I have that also in my .h file.    $@interface compassViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>{}

Comment: Puzzling. The code you posted is OK. Add a NSLog before the line `[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];` to see if that method is being called (it should be called, but I can't find an explanation for this).

Comment: viewDidLoad method is invoked perfectly, but the problem is with the [locationManager startUpdatingHeading]; method. This line in the above code is executing, but according to the property of this methode, it will automatically invoke " -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading " method, but its not happening, it should be executed for my application to run properly. Actually I am trying to make a compass application...... Help me please....... –